# Remade developer cert, should I remake Distribution Cert?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

So my machine went into service and they wiped it. I was trying to do an ad hoc deployment today and could not get a distribution cert to work, so I was reading threads and revoked my developer cert and made a new one. Now I think I have to remake the distribution cert, because when I try to use it it says it can't find a valid key pair. Even if I found the private key on one of my other machines, having revoked it probably means it won't work.

I had gotten to the point where I thought provisioning was not that bad. Oh well...

Comment: Also, provisioning can become a huge hassle sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wipe your computer, you lose your public+private key pairs. This results in all certificates becoming invalid, and thus requiring you to remake each and every certificate. Don't forget that intermediate certificate (WWDR)

Comment: Ok, will have to remake the distribution cert now. Oh joy.. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, Apple's process can be annoying.